# Backing up portion of data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge schema containing billions of records, I want to purge data older than 13 months from it and maintain it as a backup in such a way that it can be recovered again whenever required.

Which is the best way to do it in SQL - can we create a separate copy of this schema and add a delete trigger on all tables so that when trigger fires, purged data gets inserted to this new schema?

Will there be only one record per delete statement if we use triggers? Or all records will be inserted? 
    Can we somehow use bulk copy?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).  Are you trying to improve the performance of your database by reducing the number of stored records?  Have you already tried partitioning the larger tables?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this is a perfect use case for the Stretch Database feature in SQL Server 2016.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn935011.aspx

The cold data can be moved to the cloud with your given date criteria without any applications or users being aware of it when querying the database. No backups required and very easy to setup.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for triggers, you can use job running every day, that will put outdated data into archive tables.

The best way I guess is to create a copy of current schema. In main part - delete all that is older then 13 months, in archive part - delete all for last 13 month.

Than create SP (or any SPs) that will collect data - put it into archive and delete it from main table. Put this is into daily running job.

Comment: Mine is a one time job, I need to do it only once because the data is been taking a lot of space making its performance poor on the front end. I have already created scripts that will delete the data in chunks older than 13 months. The part which remains is taking backup of the deleted data.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and fastest way to do this (with billions of rows) is to create a partitioned table probably based on a date column by month. Moving data in a given partition is a meta operation and is extremely fast (if the partition setup and its function is set up properly.) I have managed 300GB tables using partitioning and it has been very effective. Be careful with the partition function so dates at each edge are handled correctly.

Some of the other proposed solutions involve deleting millions of rows which could take a long, long time to execute. Model the different solutions using profiler and/or extended events to see which is the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above to not create a trigger.  Triggers fire with every insert/update/delete making them very slow.

You may be best served with a data archive stored procedure.

Consider using multiple databases.  The current database that has your current data.  Then an archive or multiple archive databases where you move your records out from your current database to with some sort of say nightly or monthly stored procedure process that moves the data over.

You can use the exact same schema as your production system.

If the data is already in the database no need for a Bulk Copy.  From there you can backup your archive database so it is off the sql server.  Restore the database if needed to make the data available again.  This is much faster and more manageable than bulk copy.

Comment: My database has multiple schemas, out of which these billion records are in one schema, is it possible to take backup of only this particular schema with data? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's documentation on Stretch DB (found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-server-stretch-database/), you can't update or delete rows that have been migrated to cold storage or rows that are eligible for migration.

So while Stretch DB does look like a capable technology for archive, the implementation in SQL 2016 does not appear to support archive and purge.